# Get largest value in multi-dimensional array javascript or coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, coffeescript

I have an array that looks like the following:

```
array = [[1, 5], [4, 7], [3, 8], [2, 3],  
 [12, 4], [6, 6], [4, 1], [3, 2], 
 [8, 14]]
```

What I need is the largest number from the first value of the sets, so in this case `12`.
Looking at some examples online, the best way I saw to accomplish this is :

```
Math.max.apply Math, array
```

Problem is, this only works with single dimensional arrays. How would I impliment this for my senario? (jquery allowed)

---

**The end solution:**

It wasn't part of the question, but I needed both the min and max from the array, and that changes things a little.

```
    unless device.IE
        justTheDates    = magnitudeArray.map (i) -> i[0]
        @earliest       = Math.min.apply Math, justTheDates
        @latest         = Math.max.apply Math, justTheDates                 
    else
        @earliest       = magnitudeArray[0][0]
        @latest         = magnitudeArray[0][0]
        for magnitudeItem in magnitudeArray
            @earliest   = magnitudeItem[0] if magnitudeItem[0] < @earliest
            @latest     = magnitudeItem[0] if magnitudeItem[0] > @latest
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()`...

```
array.reduce(function(max, arr) { 
    return Math.max(max, arr[0]); 
}, -Infinity)
```

---

Here's a version that doesn't use `Math.max`...

```
array.reduce(function(max, arr) {
    return max >= arr[0] ? max : arr[0];
}, -Infinity);
```

...and a [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/max-using-map-vs-reduce).

Comment: +1 For a classic fold example :). A CoffeeScript [translation](http://coffeescript.org/#try:array%20%3D%20[[1%2C%205]%2C%20[4%2C%207]%2C%20[3%2C%208]%2C%20[2%2C%203]]%0A%0Amax%20%3D%20array.reduce%20%28%28max%2C%20arr%29%20-%3E%20Math.max%20max%2C%20arr[0]%29%2C%20-Infinity%0Aconsole.log%20max): `max = array.reduce ((max, arr) -> Math.max max, arr[0]), -Infinity`

Comment: I am seeing more votes for this answer. Would someone be interested in making a case for it OVer the one I accepted?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: I wouldn't want to say that one is better than the other. A `.reduce()` just evaluates an Array down to a single value. A `.map()` is basically a `.reduce()` that evaluates it down to a new collection. So a `.map()` behavior can be achieved using `.reduce()` like this: `array.reduce(function(arr, curr) { arr.push(curr[0]); return arr; }, [])`. And then you'd still use `Math.max.apply...`. The advantage using the `.map()` style with `.apply` is that you avoid the repeated `Math.max` calls. The advantage of reducing directly to a number is perhaps a little clarity.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: FYI, I posted another version that doesn't use `Math.max`, as well as a jsPerf test.

Comment: @amnotiam looks like neither `.map` or `.reduce` is suppored by ie8! What to do now?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Shim it with patches from MDN. [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Compatibility) This way you can code using modern techniques immediately.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah I found how the shim works and just implemented a loop for ie8-

Comment: is it possible to get the other values from the 'max' value?  ex: if `[8, 14]` 8 is the high value how can i get `14`?

Comment: @tq: `return Math.max.apply(Math, arr.concat(max))`

Answer (score 9):

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/HM7es/

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function(i) {
    return i[0];
}));​
```

So at first you use `array.map()` to convert the 2-dimensional array to a flat one, and after that use `Math.max()`

Comment: I am not familiar with .map can you explain what is going on there?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map --- so it applies a callback to each element. In your case each `i` is a `[1, 5]` - array of 2 elements, and you just return first item. After `arr.map()` is applied you have another array, that contains 1st elements of each nested array

Comment: I guess my question is ... is .map more or less efficient than a loop?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: I'm sure it is very close to it and I'm also sure it is not a thing you need to think about now. Choose the solution you can read/maintain better

Comment: CoffeeScript often suggests node, but it might be worth noting that `Array#map` isn't supported <= IE8

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution using Underscore.js' [`max`](http://underscorejs.org/#max) that avoids generating an intermediate array:

```
max = _(array).max(_.first)[0]
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28u98/2/))

Comment: I am NOT going to include an entire new lib just do solve this.

Comment: OK, then the other solutions will work better :). Underscore has many useful little functions that, in my experience, are used quite often; and it's only 4KB, so, if it is because of library size, you are not in danger of bloating too much when including it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a comprehension in CoffeeScript:

```
Math.max.apply Math, (x[0] for x in array)
```

[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ymfx/)

Comment: Splats [can do the job too](http://jsfiddle.net/6ymfx/1/): `Math.max (x[0] for x in array) ...` :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, look at _underscore.js. [Here is a link to the function _max().](http://underscorejs.org/#max)

- It is simply more efficient to read, write and maintain.

The best part about _underscore is that there are about another hundred helper functions similar to _max. Like sort.

Compare the syntax below:

```
var sortedObject = _.sortBy(object, function(val, key, object) {
    return val;
});
```

They are easy to chain, and interpret!
(Like Douglas Crockford might suggest)

An excellent [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/rNvFy/1/), was provided in [this post by @Raynos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929924/how-to-sort-a-javascript-object-or-convert-it-to-an-array).

If you are consistently conducting array operations with raw JavaScript, check out _underscore.js, it can greatly simplify your code.

Hope that helps,
All the best!
Nash

Comment: "It is simply more efficient" --- how the library can be more efficient than the underlying language?

Comment: Good question, more efficient to write (to read, and maintain). Thanks for the clarification @zerkms. +1. Edited.

Comment: I am NOT going to include an entire new lib just do solve this.

Comment: Correct. This is for those that are "consistently conducting array operations with raw JavaScript". Some environments are such. If maintaining advanced algorithms this may be an optimization for you. It also comes with a powerful templating engine for advanced data-binding.

Comment: Frankly I am not impressed with underscore.

Comment: Can you tell us of its shortcomings or downsides? With so many .js libraries, whether one is good or bad often comes down to best fit for context and environment. Hope this helps. All the best! Nash (Thanks for your assessment).

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.maxX = function(){
  return Math.max.apply(Math,this.map(function(o){return o[0];}));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but if you (or someone else) want the largest number in the whole array, try with:

```
var array = [[1, 5], [4, 7], [3, 8], [2, 3],  
 [12, 4], [6, 6], [4, 1], [3, 2], 
 [8, 14]];

var max = array.reduce(function (max, arr) {
    return max >= Math.max.apply(max, arr) ? max : Math.max.apply(max, arr);
}, -Infinity);
console.log(max);
```

In this examlpe, it will return the value 14.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Input:
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

    var largest = 0;
    var largestArr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){

        if(largest < arr[i][j]){
          largest = arr[i][j];
        }
        largestArr[i] = largest;
      }      
      largest = 0;
    }

  return largestArr;
}
```

You can populate largest numbers into new Array from two dim array.

Answer (score 0):

ES2019 Array.prototype.flat() with destructuring.

```
const max = Math.max(...arr.flat());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat