# Get min-max numbers from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an array like this:

```
array = [[1, 5, 8, 9], [3, 7], [3, 8, 33], [2], [0, 6]]
```

I need to find max and min values from this array. In this case, `max = 33, min = 0`

I saw examples of array reduce, but I don't want to find max value for particular index of the inner array.

Comment: Is the array always 2 dimensional or could it have more?

Comment: @aurbano, yes, it is 2 dimensional always.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149843/get-largest-value-in-multi-dimensional-array-javascript-or-coffeescript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just try with:

```
var flat = [];
$.map(array, function(item){ $.merge(flat, item); });

// or merge arrays using `join` and `split`

var flat = array.join().split(',');

var max = Math.max.apply( Math, flat ),
    min = Math.min.apply( Math, flat );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is pure JS based solution. Without jQuery:

```
var flattened = [[1, 5, 8, 9], [3, 7], [3, 8, 33], [2], [0, 6]].reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
});

Math.max.apply(null, flattened) //33

Math.min.apply(null, flattened) // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Without jquery, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values) to add max and min to arrays:

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
   return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
   return Math.min.apply(null, this);
 };
```

The answer becomes:

```
 arr = [[1, 5, 8, 9], [3, 7], [3, 8, 33], [2], [0, 6]]
 maxm = arr.map(function(a){return a.max()}).max();
 minm = arr.map(function(a){return a.min()}).min();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var array=[[1, 5, 8, 9], [3, 7], [3, 8, 33], [2], [0, 6]];
var newArr=array.join().replace(/\[\]/,"").split(',').map(function(x){return +x}); 
Math.max.apply(null,newArr); // 33
Math.min.apply(null,newArr); // 0
```

Comment: You are outStandable. Great no words to say

Answer (score 1):

```
min = max = array[0][0]
for (i in array)
    for (j in array[i]) {
        if (array[i][j] > max) max = array[i][j]
        if (array[i][j] < min) min = array[i][j]    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With underscorejs:

```
var array = [[1, 5, 8, 9], [3, 7], [3, 8, 33], [2], [0, 6]];
var max = _.chain(array)
           .flatten()
           .max()
           .value()
```

Pretty self explanatory to get min.