# Max value of a multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of x columns and y rows.
How can I find the min and the max value of the matrix?
Example:

```
[[1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
[2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
[3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
[4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
[5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
[6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
[7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
[8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
[9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
[10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
[11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
[12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
[13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
[14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]]
```

Comment: show that *multidimensional array* at start

Comment: put whole code , that you tried, if you have not tried, no one is there to do work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get largest value in multi-dimensional array javascript or coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149843/get-largest-value-in-multi-dimensional-array-javascript-or-coffeescript)

Comment: Please share the exact example of multidimensional array. This is not a proper multidimensional array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

let

```
var arr = [[2,3], [4,5]]; // a multidimensional array
```

then get an array with each row's maximum with

```
var maxRow = arr.map(function(row){ return Math.max.apply(Math, row); });
```

and the overal maximum with

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, maxRow);
```

Comment: How would you get max of every column or of say columns 2-5?

Answer (score 8):

Regardless of the dimension of the array, i believe this is the way to get the max of all primitives involved.

```js
function getMax(a){
  return Math.max(...a.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? getMax(e) : e));
}

var arr = [[1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
           [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
           [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
           [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
           [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
           [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
           [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
           [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
           [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
           [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
           [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
           [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
           [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
           [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]];
 console.log(getMax(arr));
```

It should work on arrays with indefinite dimension.

```js
function getMax(a){
  return Math.max(...a.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? getMax(e) : e));
}

var arr = [[1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
           [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
           [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
           [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
           [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
           [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
           [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
           [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
           [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
           [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
           [11,  5.3,  [6.1,[56.7,[98.55]]],  4.7],
           [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
           [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
           [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]];
 console.log(getMax(arr));
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Simplest Solution

Flatten and use the usual `Math.max` with spread operator.

`Math.max(...arr.flat())`

```
const arr = [[1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
           [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
           [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
           [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
           [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
           [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
           [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
           [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
           [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
           [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
           [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
           [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
           [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
           [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]];

Math.max(...arr.flat())
```

Comment: The shortest working solution I have seen!

Answer (score 5):

You can get max value of multi dimension array using following method:

```
var arr = [[1, 5,6], [4, 7,8], [3, 8,20], [2, 3,1],[12, 4,5]];

console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function (i) {
    return i[0]+i[1]+i[2];
})));
```

It first use array.map() to convert the multi-dimensional array to a flat one, and after that use Math.max().

Comment: Any reason for down voting this answer?

Answer (score 4):

Most answers here use `apply` or the spread operator `...` to call the `Math.max` function with all the elements of an array as parameters.

For large arrays it is safer to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
// returns maximum of an array
const getArrayMax = array => array.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b));

// returns maximum of a 2D array
const getArrayMax2d = array2d => getArrayMax(array2d.map(getArrayMax));
```

Comment: You can do ```getArrayMax(array2d.map(getArrayMax));``` instead of ```getArrayMax(array2d.map(row => getArrayMax(row)));```

Answer (score 1):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47691794/2379009) answer, you can do it in 1 line (assuming ES6):

```
const arr = [[12,45,75], [54,45,2],[23,54,75,2]];

const max = Math.max(...[].concat(...arr));

const min = Math.min(...[].concat(...arr));

console.log(max);

console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `Array.prototype.push`, `Math.min` and `Math.max` methods:

```
// arr is your initial array
var flattened = [], minValue, maxValue;
arr.forEach(function (v) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(flattened, v);
});

minValue = Math.min.apply(null, flattened);
maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, flattened);

console.log('min: ' + minValue, 'max: ' + maxValue);  // min: 1 max: 80.8
```

[DEMO link](https://jsfiddle.net/e9g6t0aL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with a reduction (it's slower but if the array is not huge, it doesn't matter) resulting in a object containing both the min and the max like so:

```
matrix.reduce(function (res, item) {
    item.forEach(function (val) {
        if (!res.hasOwnProperty('max') || val > res.max) res.max = val;
        if (!res.hasOwnProperty('min') || val < res.min) res.min = val;
    });
    return res;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i could i would comment this on DankMasterDan's answer

```
let a = [[12,45,75], [54,45,2],[23,54,75,2]];
let max = Math.max(...a.map(r=>Math.max(...r)));
```

this may avoid the stack size exceeded error.
David mentioned since its is batching each row with the map first.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to your solution very simple way

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let maxValue;
  let arrMax = []
for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
maxValue = Math.max.apply(null ,arr[i])
arrMax.push(maxValue)
}
  return arrMax;
}
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
 return --> [ 5, 27, 39, 1001 ]
```