# Find the Max and Min element out of all the nested arrays of nested arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Find max and min of nested array of nested array like

```js
var arry=[1,2,[14,56,34,[48,98]],[14,16,11,[18,81]],34,35]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could flat the array first and then take the wanted method with spreaded values.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, [14, 56, 34, [48, 98]], [14, 16, 11, [18, 81]], 34, 35],
    flat = array.flat(Infinity),
    min = Math.min(...flat),
    max = Math.max(...flat);

console.log(min, max);
```

Comment: plus the options in your [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47691971/13762301) answer