# Can I pick a cell from every Google Sheet in a Folder?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to pick say C3 from a list of Google spreadsheets in a folder.

I have a bunch of structurally identical sheets, but I'd like to be able to provide a sum of the values in C3 across say a hundred sheets in a directory.

Ultimately, would be great to highlight the largest or smallest value of C3 in a directory.

This could be useful in many places where you want to be able to aggregate, aggregate data.

Comment: for a hundred sheets its best to use a script but if you really want you can do it with just long formula

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

If you have hundreds of Google spreadsheet files in a Google Drive folder, I agree with [@player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) that it is best to use a script. With the [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects), you can:

1. Automate the process in iterating through Spreadsheet files in your Drive folder.
2. Filter only the Google Spreadsheet type (e.g you have a bunch of
   different file types inside).
3. Get the range data & process them the way you want.

See this sample below that was derived from existing resources:

## Script:

```
function readSheetsInAFolder() {
  //FOLDER_ID is your drive folder ID
  var query = '"FOLDER_ID" in parents and trashed = false and ' +
    'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"';
  var range = "C3"; //The range to look for on every Spreadsheet files in the Drive folder
  var files, pageToken;
  var finalRes = [];

  do {
    files = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    files.items.forEach(sheet => {
      finalRes.push(viewRangeValue(range, sheet.id));
    })
    pageToken = files.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  const arrSum = array =>
    array.reduce(
        (sum, num) => sum + (Array.isArray(num) ? arrSum(num) : num * 1),
        0
    );

    var max = Math.max.apply(null, finalRes.map(function(row){ return Math.max.apply(Math, row) })); //Gets the largest number
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, finalRes.map(function(row){ return Math.min.apply(Math, row); })); //Gets the smallest number
    var sum = arrSum(finalRes) // Gets the sum
    console.log('RANGE VALUES: %s \nRANGE: %s \nTOTAL SHEET(s) FOUND: %s \n________________\nSUM OF VALUES: %s \nLargest Value: %s \nSmallest Value: %s',finalRes,range, files.items.length,sum,max,min)
}

function viewRangeValue(range, sheetID) {
  var sid = sheetID;
  var rn = range;
  var parms = { valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE', dateTimeRenderOption: 'SERIAL_NUMBER' };
  var res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sid, rn, parms);
  return res.values.map(num => {return parseInt(num)});
}
```

## Demonstration:

- Sample Test Drive Folder (w/ 3 test Spreadsheet files):

> Every `C3` cell on each of these 3 files contain either `0`,`10` or `6` value.

[image]

- On the Apps Script Editor, I've added the **Drive** & **Sheets** API on the services:

[image]

## Result

After running the script:

[image]

### Resources:

- [Advanced Drive Service](https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/advanced/drive.html)
- [Drive API Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Sheets API spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get#query-parameters)
- [Max Value of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39342975)