# Underscore: Wrap array with collection methods

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array full of objects:

```
var myArray = [{ "user": "anton" }, { "user": "joe" }];
```

I would now like to wrap the array into a Underscore Collection object so that I can nativly use underscore's collection methods (remove, add) with it:

```
myArray = _(myArray); // this only add object methods
myArray.add({ "user": "paul" });
```

So how do I wrap an array with underscore to use underscores collection methods

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4929935/950890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally underscore api doesn't wrap array or object. just passing it first argument.
ex)

```
_.first([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]); //Note first argument
=> 5
var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

But chain (`_.chain(obj)`) Returns a wrapped object. Calling methods on this object will continue to return wrapped objects until value is used.

```
var stooges = [{name : 'curly', age : 25}, {name : 'moe', age : 21}, {name : 'larry', age : 23}];
var youngest = _.chain(stooges)
  .sortBy(function(stooge){ return stooge.age; })
  .map(function(stooge){ return stooge.name + ' is ' + stooge.age; })
  .first()
  .value();
=> "moe is 21"
```

check underscore api : http://underscorejs.org/#

Comment: @hyogron check ggozad's answer~

Answer (score 7):

For the record since the accepted answer is missleading:

Underscore used as a function, **will** wrap its argument, i.e.

```
_([a, b, c])
```

is equivalent to:

```
_.chain([a, b, c])
```

In fact `chain` is defined as:

```
_.chain = function(obj) {
  return _(obj).chain();
};
```

Now to your question:

You confuse Backbone which provides Collections, with Underscore which does not. Backbone collections can be easily initialized from an array, for example:

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection([{ "user": "anton" }, { "user": "joe" }]);
```

will work just fine. You can further do:

```
c.add({ "user": "paul" });
```

Comment: `_([a, b, c])` isn't equivalent to `_.chain([a, b, c])`